# How to extract cnn features from images?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to extract features from the image as a part of retrieval task.Now I want to extract cnn features from image and match it with cnn features with the other images. I am not performing any sort of classification task. I am stuck with extracting features. I would like to extract features using keras tensorflow.

Comment: Can you provide us with some actual code? What did you try so far?

Comment: Pass your image through your network, extract the output of last conv layer and then you can match these features with other images features using some sort of metric like L1 or L2, whichever is good for your case

Comment: Still at present I  am facing problem in executing code. I am using python 2.7 and trying to install tensorflow.

Comment: By features, you mean saliency maps and stuffs? If that's the case try Keras-vis.